# INSERT Error - 1064

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a function that is supposed to takes x2 String Inputs and INSERTs them into a mySQL database.  The two strings are query results and could be anything.  I am getting this error during testing.

> ex    {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's a good start, but I can guarantee you it won't be. He doesn'
>   at line 1"}   System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

After some thought I came the the conclusion that it errors out because one of my strings contains the apostrophe ' character and is messing with the mySQL syntax.  What can I do to my strings to make sure they can be INSERT-ed as is with all their characters into my table?

I have tried string manipulation & using the AddWithValue() function but neither has worked so far.  I thought using the Replace function would help, but I am usure what is the proper mySQL syntax I wish to output.

Any thoughts / advice appreciated.  Thank you.

```
public void Insert(string SearchQuery, string QueryResult)
        {
            const string connString = "SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=social_db; UID=root; PASSWORD=pass;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

            QueryResult = QueryResult.Replace("'", "\'");

            command.CommandText =
                "INSERT INTO social_tbl (SearchQuery, QueryResult)"
                + " VALUES "
                + "('" + SearchQuery + "', '" + QueryResult + "');";

            //command.CommandText =
            //"INSERT INTO social_tbl (SearchQuery, QueryResult) VALUES ('@SearchQuery', '@QueryResult');";

            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchQuery", SearchQuery);
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QueryResult", QueryResult);

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();         
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Never concatenate parameters into an SQL string - [this opens up a very serious security hole (SQL injection!)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

use

```
        command.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO social_tbl (SearchQuery, QueryResult) VALUES (@SearchQuery, @QueryResult);";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchQuery", SearchQuery);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QueryResult", QueryResult);
```

With this you don't need `Replace` and use "bind parameters" which makes you secure from SQL injection and sometimes even benefits performance. In your original code you had `'` around each parameter - this is neither needed not would it work (as you already discovered) when working with "bind parameters".

Comment: This helped eliminate my error but this inserts NULL values into my data table.  The DataType of SearchQuery & QueryResult is just Text, if the string I'm passing is too large, what should I be doing / using here?

Comment: @Draznar you should always check incoming data and if it is too large you either throw an exception and/or change the width of the DB columns and/or shorten the parameters appropriately depending on your requirements...

Comment: @Draznar please don't forget to upvote and/or "mark as accepted" any answer that was of help...

Comment: @ Yahia - I think something else is causing an issue.  Even if I try to insert small strings using the "bind parameters" with the AddWithValue method, only NULL value is being inserted into my table.  Any Thoughts (or should I be making a seperate Question Post)?

    SearchQuery = "Test 1";
    QueryResult = "Test 2";

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO socialmention_tbl (SearchQuery, QueryResult) VALUES (@SearchQuery, @QueryResult);";

Comment: @Draznar and what is causing an issue ?

Comment: @ Yahia - It still inserts NULL values into my table even on a simple string such as "Test 1", see above edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO social_tbl ('SearchQuery', 'QueryResult')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure why, but after looking at some other questions for insight, I found that using the '?' instead of the '@' char. seems to have solved my issue.

```
command.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO socialm_tbl (SearchQuery, QueryResult) VALUES (?SearchQuery, ?QueryResult);";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?SearchQuery", SearchQuery);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?QueryResult", QueryResult);
```